# Override sharepoint emailing service with your own

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a REST web-service which every application in my organization uses to send out emails instead of using anything external.  Basically, it accepts, body, subject, TO, FROM etc...And sends out an email.

Is it possible to configure Sharepoint to use my service instead of using it's own internal emailing setup to send emails?  Basically I was looking for a way to override the place in the code where the emails are about to be sent and just drop my own code in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not possible. You would have to develop your own notification system and plug it in [SharePoint's event receiver facilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx).

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on the event handlers in sharepoint?  Maybe a link, I'm having trouble finding any information.